# Should we have separate tags for the Maya, Inca and Aztec mythologies?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have separate tags for the Roman and Greek mythologies, despite the fact that these mythologies are very closely intertwined - often even the same stories, only the actors having different names. Like the story of Venus / Aphrodite cheating Vulcanus / Hefaistos with Mars / Ares.

The native peoples of South America seem to have similarly intertwined pantheons. I'm not an expert on these religions, but as I understand it they are alike in a similar way to the Greek and Roman mythology.

Should we have separate tags for "Maya", "Inca" and "Aztec"?

Comment: Don't see why not. We can also make an overarching mesoamerican tag for broader/comparative questions if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The Maya-Aztec relationship is not entirely unlike the Greek-Roman relationship. This suggests that just as we have separate tags for [greek] and [roman], we ought to have separate tags for [maya] and [aztec].

The Incas are from a separate cultural tradition altogether (Andes vs. Mexico) and barely have anything in common with the mythoi of the Aztecs and the Maya. Inca myth obviously merits a different tag.

Answer (score 5):

I think we should have separate tags for all overlapping mythologies... for now.

**Later,** it will be come more clear about whether there's enough overlap for them to be merged into one tag. At the very least, all the tags will exist, the question is, will they exist as synonyms or not. But it's not important to resolve this question right now.

It's easier to create a synonym than it is to revert it, as in the latter case you have to go through all the posts and decide which is which.

Also, as @Semaphore suggests in the comments, one solid option is to have a broader [mesoamerican](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesoamerican) tag for questions that span all three mythologies.