# What sort of separation should we have for derived religion questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, [christianity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) ultimately is an offshoot of [judaism](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism). Some stories are **exactly the same**, the ones in the Old Testament, unlike [this question, where there is a lot of cultural overlap but the stories aren't from the same first source](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-maya-inca-and-aztec-mythologies). Other stories in [christianity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) aren't in [judaism](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) at all, though, obviously.

So what should a question like: [Who did Adam and Eve's son Cain marry?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/135/who-did-adam-and-eves-son-cain-marry) be tagged? [christianity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity)? [judaism](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism)? Both? [judeo-christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judeo-christian)? [old-testament](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-testament)?

I'm just brainstorming here. I welcome all thoughts from the community.

Update: We now have [abrahamic-religions](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abrahamic-religions). I don't know if that adds any clarity or not.

Answer (score 7):

I personally would tag that question as [judeo-christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judeo-christian) because the story is shared by both. (Also by Islam, but that's less prominent.) In short, if it occurs in the Old Testament, especially in Genesis 1-11 (or a minor/major prophet), it should be tagged as [judeo-christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judeo-christian). There *are* plenty of stories in the Old Testament, but questions on them may be more likely to fit on Judaism.SE or Christianity.SE, so that's something to keep in mind.

**For religions in general, if a story is shared by more than one religion, tag it with both (or the combined tag if it exists).** However, I think Judaism and Christianity will be the most prominent and common, so I don't think there's much need to create tags for other possible or actual religion overlaps.

Comment: I was under impression that (from Christian POV) some of Old Testament was "invalidated", for lack of a better term? (I figure you'd know far better than me). So it may be a bit shadier than "5 books" as far as bucketing. I agree with the concept in the answer, though.

Comment: @DVK: "Invalidated" in the sense that we no longer have to follow the Mosaic Law to be saved. Most Christians still believe that the events in the Old Testament actually happened. All of the Old Testament is actually shared by both Jews and Christians, the books are just ordered differently. Hmm. Come to think of it, Genesis is pretty much the only one of the first five that contains mythic stories, but several other books also have mythic stories. I'll edit my answer.